# Shape animation in iOS

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, timer, shapes

I have an UIView in which I draw many shapes. I just want to keep redrawing this view in order  to make kind of an animation. I searched for animation options, but all animations looks like they only work with properties, like transform, alpha... I just want a timed animation option, and that do not block the screen, I mean, that allows the application to realize the screen was tapped. Is it possible?

Comment: Could you explain a little more on the nature of your animations? Is it like a frame-image-animation, that is, like an animated cartoon? Or should it animate the drawing of vector based shapes, that is, like someone magically draws those shapes slowly on the screen? Or else..?

Comment: The shapes are simples geometric shapes drawn using Quartz, like rectangles. After some processing, they can change color/position. I just want keep doing this processing and changing these shapes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is totally possible and you have a few different ways that you can go about doing it.  If you want a simple png sequence style animation you can just fill a UIImageView like this:

```
imageView.animationImages = myImages;
imageView.animationDuration = 3;
[imageView startAnimating];
```

or you can override the drawrect function in a custom UIView, set up an NSTimer to tick however frequently you want to change the animation and call setNeedsDisplay on the view to draw the next frame.

Comment: Actually I draw the shapes using Quartz, and I want to animate these shapes changing colors/position after some processing.

Comment: Core Animation is definitely another way to go.  I've not used the shape animations, CAShapeLayer, as mentioned in another answer, but it's probably the best way to go.  I have used Core Animation for 2d and 3d translation, rotation and scaling animations and it's a very powerful and customizable solution.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a bezier path that represents each shape, try looking at `CAShapeLayer` - this can be used to draw a path on the screen, and you can animate the position, fill colour and many other properties of it.

Have one CAShapeLayer per shape, and add them as sub layers to your main view's layer.

You need to add the QuartzCore framework to use it, but it is very straightforward and there are plenty of tutorials out there.

Comment: Should I have one CAShapeLayer for each shape I wanna draw?

Comment: Yes, each one only holds one path, and also this way you can move/recolour them individually.